# Is it possible to alter the NAME of a partition function in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, function, partitioning, partition, sql-server-2019

I'm working on some large tables where the partition functions need to be split. I have a process in place, but I figure it might be easier to just create new tables with the new, correct partition and partition functions, switch to the new table and then rename the new table with the old tables name.

However, I'm having a hard time finding any statement that would allow me to change the name of the function itself. This is the only code I could find in the documents that would alter the function. If it is not possible to change the name of the partition function, is it possible to switch partitions from table to table if they do not share the same partition function?

```
ALTER PARTITION FUNCTION partition_function_name()  
{   
    SPLIT RANGE ( boundary_value )  
  | MERGE RANGE ( boundary_value )   
} [ ; ]
```

Comment: `sp_rename` can only rename objects that are tracked in `sys.objects`. Partition Functions are not one of those things.

Comment: Since the source table will be empty after switching data to the new table, perform the same partition split/merge operations against the original function/scheme and switch all partitions back to the original table.

Comment: this was a solution I was gravitating toward. Tell me this, can two different partition functions use the same partition schema?

Comment: A partition scheme is tied to a single function so you can't have 2 functions use the same scheme.